# Logging sent data in an ajax request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've got my code like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: { Name: name, TableData: tableData },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

It's just a simple name string, and an array of data from a table

But when I send this to the controller, how can I display the data sent in a log in visual studio or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your data into a variable and log that like this:

```
var data = { Name: name, TableData: tableData };
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     data: data,
     dataType: 'json'
 });
console.log(data);
```